# Resolve type from prop on interface that is enum

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So I have a big web application. which resolves alot around entities.
For example:

```
enum EntityTypes {
  EntityA = 'A',
  EntityB = 'B',
  EntityC = 'C',
  EntityD = 'D',
}

interface EntityA {
  type: EntityTypes.EntityA;
  aSpecialProperty: boolean;
}

interface EntityB {
  type: EntityTypes.EntityB;
  bSpecialProperty: boolean;
}

interface EntityC {
  type: EntityTypes.EntityC;
  cSpecialProperty: string;
}

interface EnityD {
  type: EntityTypes.EntityD;
  dSpecialProperty: number;
}
```

We do so because we later want to resolve properties that are unique to every type like this (and this is how we do it until now):

```
type EntityTypesResolver<T extends EntityTypes> = T extends EntityTypes.EntityA
  ? EntityA
  : T extends EntityTypes.EntityB
  ? EntityB
  : T extends EntityTypes.EntityC
  ? EntityC
  : T extends EntityTypes.EntityD
  ? EntityD
  : never;

type EntityResolver<ResultType> = {
  [P in EntityTypes]: (entity: EntityTypesResolver<P>) => ResultType;
};

const resolver: EntityResolver<string> = {
  [EntityTypes.EntityA]: (entity) => `${entity.aSpecialProperty}`,
  [EntityTypes.EntityB]: (entity) => `${entity.bSpecialProperty}`,
  [EntityTypes.EntityC]: (entity) => entity.cSpecialProperty,
  [EntityTypes.EntityD]: (entity) => `${entity.dSpecialProperty}`,
};
```

**The problem**: I want to eliminate (or find a more elegant solution) the `EntityTypesResolver` because it seems like an error-prone code block for a couple of reasons:

1. As we are a large team working on this codebase, i do not want to rely on other programmers remembering to maintain this type
2. The readiblity here is terrible

I tried to find an elegant solution for this for lots of time, but didn't seem to achieve something.

Solution proposed by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz):
my problem with this solution is that I still have to rely on other programmers to maintain `Entity` type alias.
// these two lines

```
type Entity = EntityA | EntityB | EntityC | EntityD
type EntityTypesResolver<T extends EntityTypes> = Extract<Entity, { type: T }>
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDz3RW) meet your needs?  You maintain a union like `type Entity =  EntityA | EntityB | EntityC | EntityD` to which you can add new union members when you need to.  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your question to show the unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: @jcalz , edited the post as requested

Comment: TypeScript can't "discover" your entity interfaces by itself (there's no way to iterate known interfaces, and you wouldn't even want this someone could add a new `interface Whoopsie {type: EntityTypes.EntityB, randomThing: string}` somewhere and break your code; you need to tell it which ones they are.  Something like `type Entity = EntityA | EntityB | EntityC | EntityD` is probably the lightest weight way to do it (especially compared to your original version). If you're willing to refactor significantly, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m05rnW) you can make it more automatic.

Comment: If that last refactor works for you, then I can write that up.  If it doesn't, and you need to have hand-created interfaces `EntityA`, `EntityB` in scope, then you will have to also manually put them in a bag for the compiler to find.  Let me know which sort of answer you want to see.  In the worst case I would just answer with my original suggestion, which is an improvement over your current code, along with the caveats for why it can't get any better.

Comment: @jcalz is there any way I can enforce the EntityTypeResolver so that the union passed will include all enum keys?

Comment: Sorry, in which code? There's your code example in the question and then I have two playground links in these comments.  And I'm not sure which `EntityTypeResolver` you're talking about and what you mean by "union passed".  Can you show precisely what you're talking about in a [mre], preferably in a playground link? (you can use https://tsplay.dev to make short playground links for comments).

Comment: @jcalz. [tsplay.dev example](https://tsplay.dev/wX24Dm) , i provided the entire code with a comment on the thing im talking about. Just asking is there any way I can validate the type Entity contains all the enum keys

Comment: Oh I understand now.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK7g8W) do what you want?

Comment: That's great, care to explain the ```=void``` assignment?

Comment: We're not going to use the type `EntityCompletenessCheck` anywhere so we can assign any type we want to it.  I chose `void` but it doesn't matter.  The important part is within the generic type parameter constraint and default, which will be an error if and only if your `Entity` type is incomplete.  Now, do you want this as an answer?  I can write it up if this addresses the issue raised in the question.

Comment: Yes, greatly appriciated :) also I tried playing with the example: but can't seem to understand how does the ```T extends Entity['type'] = EntityTypes``` works.

Comment: Okay I will do that; it might not be for five or six hours though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `EntityTypesResolver<T>` type function selects an interface from a known set of interfaces based on the member of `EntityTypes` passed in for `T`.  Currently it does this via a series of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and this works, but as you say it's not very readable.

It's more natural and readable to turn those interfaces into a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and define `EntityTypesResolver` to [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) one or more members of that union based on the `type` discriminant property.  That looks like this:

```
type Entity = EntityA | EntityB | EntityC | EntityD;
type EntityTypesResolver<T extends EntityTypes> = Extract<Entity, { type: T }>;
```

So the readability problem is solved.

---

Unfortunately, there's no getting around the fact that the compiler cannot know which set of interfaces `EntityTypesResolver` should consult, unless you tell it.  And so someone is going to have to maintain the `Entity` type by making sure that it contains a member corresponding to each member of the `EntityTypes` enum.  There's no way to ask the compiler to, for example, scan through all interfaces it knows about and select the ones which have a `type` property of the right sort.

One thing you *can* do (and thanks for the suggestion) is write some code which will generate a compiler warning if and only if the `Entity` union is missing any `EntityTypes` enum values from its members.  One approach is to define a dummy [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) whose type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the union of all the `type` properties in `Entity`, and which [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `EntityTypes`, which is the union of all `EntityTypes` enum values.  Generic parameter defaults must extend their constraints, so this line of code serves to check whether `Entity` is complete:

```
type EntityCompletenessCheck<T extends Entity['type']
  = EntityTypes> = void;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- is there an error here?
// if so, then the Entity union is missing at least one entry from EntityTypes
```

Note that the union of all the `type` properties in `Entity` is written as `Entity['type']`, an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) which answers the question: "if I have a value `e` of type `Entity` and index into it with a value of type `'type'`... that is, `e.type`, what is the type of the value I read?"  Since `Entity` is a union and every member of that union has a different `type` property, you end up with a union of these.

Also note that `EntityCompletenessCheck` is a dummy type that we're not using for anything but error checking, so its name and its value don't matter.  I called it `EntityCompletenessCheck` and assigned `void` to it, but you can call it `Foo` and assign `"bar"` to it if you want.

Anyway in the above code, there is no error.  But if I were to add a new value to `EntityTypes` without a corresponding entry in `Entity`, like this:

```
enum EntityTypes {
  EntityA = 'A',
  EntityB = 'B',
  EntityC = 'C',
  EntityD = 'D',
  EntityE = 'E', // <-- new enum member
}
type Entity = EntityA | EntityB | EntityC | EntityD // <-- oops, forgot
```

then do you get an error:

```
type EntityCompletenessCheck<T extends Entity['type']
  = EntityTypes> = void;
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- ERROR! Type 'EntityTypes' does not satisfy the constraint 
// 'EntityTypes.EntityA | EntityTypes.EntityB | EntityTypes.EntityC | EntityTypes.EntityD'
```

which is an indication that `Entity['type']` does not capture all of `EntityTypes` enum members, and that you need to fix something (e.g, add an `EntityE` interface to the `Entity` union, or remove `EntityE` from the `EntityTypes` enum).

---

So there you go.  The code is mostly readable and if developers don't remember to maintain the `Entity` discriminated union then there will be an error which hopefully will remind them, or you.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiAuBLeBPAKigDsAzlA3gFBSwLIoCCUAvFAOQV0A0xpSqAQjfR863OxQBhbnSF8SA8gBFR0iVAD0ituRiiYzJSrAgAxgHsIEUPCjwAFojwAbRCGDmDUHMEcBDEFGAAnHwZ9CAF9CQnt4XwAzdz1HKVQqIhJUbAAuVVQMbBwAOnjKAG5WdwBlbD1EdxsABX9sH1R0gCMDAxtgTyKQsIQomLiyTgJWFOB0-KzcPMGUDiKSJrLgCqrag3rGqBa2jpAu0PC+2IzhYeSsMZPJ3Pyheag9JZWaut9NnHgfewBzfZ6InzRY75WRJcwXcYza7TQTSe4AEyelRe6zeKHS4AgTV8f1CoxO3HyVAAPicuKTblAKTNpHiLichEZMO0Ig4cDghBZlgBrAA8aG8AA9WfC8PkANp0UZ0AC6rFoEwuOAAfNwAG4GRDworKEgAPQNhqNeqgvIAtGaoNZzFyfB4vL5-D4oLbgAB+Qi6xCRFwGJg20ABgm6RAGLzWiDWHA-KDuMztdwfKBhxymHwoKCRfzQRXZOnYK5KgBKuDaat8-KFIrFUKVqoVwp8MXgvPy-vw4LSUAFQWV+YGghLODLFaHYBs8Em9bOUHF1StXlzuBl6QAFKZyJDBNchyOfLzqsqAJQ0VVjieTLpFQiGEBJu3Dmzlnxb8i7p8Vj5fEDfadg8VLjcMwUCuUDrjMJ7UKqAAGAAk+AbqgOSlOUyJrBsKBBNBLAkABtbZDC5AcKB4GCJBMHwYhKA5IsqGrK8DSYdhrB4duSqEagQgkVR5HeDMOSPHRKIYThs6ARxKDSNxEGnlAcEIfxiJCehaJYSwQQFEAA)

Comment: I’m still having trouble understanding what Entity['type'] resolves to. Can you please make it clear?

Comment: I edited the answer; see the paragraph that starts: "Note that the union"